# onload Javascript function return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, height, width

I am calling a JavaScript function where I want to validate image height and width before uploading. I return `false` value but in the source function when it is console log it gives `undefined`.

For better understanding please check the code. The code is running well but I want to get `true` and `false` from the JavaScript functions.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#userfile', function() {
  var result = ValidateAuthorImage(event, $(this));
  console.log(result);
});

function ValidateAuthorImage(event, obj) {
  var files = event.target.files;
  var valid = true;
  var height = 0;
  var width = 0;
  var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      height = img.height;
      width = img.width;
      //alert(width + " " + height);
      if (width < 700 || height < 500) {
        $("#msg_upload").html('<span style="color:red;">Please uplaod image with at least width = 700 and height  = 500 </span>');
        obj.value = "";
        return false;
      } else {
        $("#msg_upload").html('');
      }
    }
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please a little more detail

Comment: Your function only returns `false`. *However* the bigger issue is that `onload` is effectively asynchronous, so you cannot return anything from the `onload` handler function to the outer `ValidateAuthorImage()` scope. You need to change the pattern you use for image dimension validation, as what you're trying to do is not possible. I'd suggest validating the images and displaying a message/error next to the image which is failing the check.

Answer (score 0):

These would help you to find out what went wrong.

Since you expect a boolean status in return,
return true, if it is Okey.
return false, if it is not Okey.
You 'must' return with either true or false.

return without boolean (or return by default), is where you get the 'undefined' boolean status.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any more code but your returns are caught in the `image.onload` methods, which is not even called (or you didnt provide the part where you call it.
But it seems that you can do this

```js
  img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
  return img.onload()
}
```